# How to fix "The package might be corrupted or you are not allowed to open the file"

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, teamviewer

I am following [this Linuxbabe tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-teamviewer-12-ubuntu-16-04-ubuntu-16-10) to install Teamviewer in Ubuntu 16.04. But I get this error all the time.

```
user@MyDir:~$ sudo gdebi teamviewer*.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Failed to open the software package
The package might be corrupted or you are not allowed to open the file. 
Check the permissions of the file.
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt

Comment: Download the teamviewer from https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend simply double-clicking on the debian package you downloaded. It should open the "Software" app, which will let you install the package.

However, sometimes that fails silently due to a missing dependency. In that case:

1. Open a terminal window and go to the download directory, for example

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_12.0.85001_i386.deb
   ```

Or whatever the name of your debian package is. From the terminal, you'll see any errors. If there's a missing dependency, you can usually fix it with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```